# Unable to load shared library 'libdl.so' or one of its dependencies

Tags: apt, shared-library, pop-os

I'm trying to compile a project and the compilation fails due to a missing library.

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libdl.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 at Assimp.Unmanaged.UnmanagedLibrary.UnmanagedLinuxLibraryImplementation.dlopen(String fileName, Int32 flags)
 at Assimp.Unmanaged.UnmanagedLibrary.UnmanagedLinuxLibraryImplementation.NativeLoadLibrary(String path)
 at Assimp.Unmanaged.UnmanagedLibrary.UnmanagedLibraryImplementation.LoadLibrary(String path)
 at Assimp.Unmanaged.UnmanagedLibrary.LoadLibrary(String libPath)
 at Assimp.Unmanaged.UnmanagedLibrary.LoadLibrary()
 at Assimp.Unmanaged.UnmanagedLibrary.LoadIfNotLoaded()
 at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.CreatePropertyStore()
 at Assimp.AssimpContext.CreateConfigs()
 at Assimp.AssimpContext.PrepareImport()
 at Assimp.AssimpContext.ImportFile(String file, PostProcessSteps postProcessFlags)
 at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.OpenAssetImporter.Import(String filename, ContentImporterContext context) in C:\BuildAgents\MonoGameWin1\work\f7381a85a626990\MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline\OpenAssetImporter.cs:line 291
 at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.FbxImporter.Import(String filename, ContentImporterContext context) in C:\BuildAgents\MonoGameWin1\work\f7381a85a626990\MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline\FbxImporter.cs:line 24
 at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentImporter`1.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.IContentImporter.Import(String filename, ContentImporterContext context) in C:\BuildAgents\MonoGameWin1\work\f7381a85a626990\MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline\ContentImporter.cs:line 45
 at MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Builder.PipelineManager.ProcessContent(PipelineBuildEvent pipelineEvent) in C:\BuildAgents\MonoGameWin1\work\f7381a85a626990\MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline\Builder\PipelineManager.cs:line 669
```

I've been searching for known solutions in MonoGame's issue tracker on github, Google, Stackoverflow, askubuntu and here.

When checking my system if the file actually exists with `sudo find / -iname libdl.so` the file is not found. Inside `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` I can however find a `libdl.so.2` file, which sounds related.

On https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=libdl.so I can see that the `libdl.so` file is included in the `libc6-dev` package which I already had installed but reinstalled as a desperate move without any luck.

This is the result of `sudo apt-config dump | grep APT::Architecture`

```
APT::Architecture "amd64";
APT::Architectures "";
APT::Architectures:: "amd64";
APT::Architectures:: "i386";
```

This is the result of `dpkg-query --list libc6`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version         Architecture Description
+++-==============-===============-============-=================================
ii  libc6:amd64    2.34-0ubuntu3.2 amd64        GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6:i386     2.34-0ubuntu3.2 i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
```

I'm running Pop!_OS 21.10 64-bit.

What can I do to obtain the `libdl.so` file, maybe even in a healthy and supported way?

Comment: AFAIK `libc6-dev` will only provide the link to the native 64-bit runtime library; to link against the 32-bit libdl.so.2 you'd need `libc6-dev:i386`. You'll also need to enable the i386 foreign architecture in `dpkg` but I'm assuming you've already done that if you've got to this point

Comment: I'm actually not sure if the compiler wants the 32-bit variant of the library. I can see I also have the `libdl.so.2` file in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` but in either case `libdl.so` is not found. It is however the `libc6-dev:amd64` that is installed and not `libc6-dev:i386`. Trying to install `libc6-dev:i386`, opens a box of i386 dependencies that very quickly ends up having dependencies on pop-desktop, which I'm not sure I want to test my luck with.

Comment: OK sorry you confused me by mentioning `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

Comment: The library file is libdl.so, not liblibdl.so as mentioned in the first line of the message. So you may have to check the spelling of the library name in your project build Makefile or whatever.

Comment: @BrahimGaabab it has to be some make file for the Assimp library as I don't have any make files in my project, but let's say I find the make file and fix the reference, I still don't have the `libdl.so` file on my machine. Do you have any idea as to how I would obtain that now that installing `libc6-dev` package does not install the file?

Comment: Could you please send the results of the following (with `sudo`): 
`apt-config dump | grep APT::Architecture`, 
`dpkg-query --list libc6`

Comment: @BrahimGaabab sure, I have updated the question with the result of both commands

Comment: Apparently `libdl.so.2` is the same as `libdl.so` but with a specific version number so I do have the file

Comment: I have libc6 2.27 and The `libdl.so` is actually a link to the `libdl.so.2`. But for your case, have a look [here](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-August/129718.html). In the release notes, (first point), it is said that `libdl.so` is embedded into libc library starting from 2.34, which is yours. This may give a clue on why the file is absent. May be you need to pick an older version of the OS in a container (the 20.04 LTS). Hope this helps.

Comment: That was a really good idea with trying an older OS version. I went back to 18.04 but with no success. 17.10 is not really cooperative in its current form so I will need to spend some time figuring out how to fix the broken URL's before I can test it.

Comment: @BrahimGaabab I managed to make it work with Ubuntu 16.04. Create your suggestion about trying older distributions as a source and I will accept your answer as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, you should check which libraries (with exact versions) are required for the build.

The `dl` library is now part of the C standard library. The [release notes](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-August/129718.html), tells that, starting from version 2.34, which is yours,

> ...all functionality formerly
> implemented in the libraries libpthread, libdl, libutil, libanl has
> been integrated into libc.  New applications do not need to link with
> -lpthread, -ldl, -lutil, -lanl anymore.  For backwards compatibility,
> empty static archives libpthread.a, libdl.a, libutil.a, libanl.a are
> provided, so that the linker options keep working.  Applications which
> have been linked against glibc 2.33 or earlier continue to load the
> corresponding shared objects (which are now empty).

This means that you have to pick an older version of the `libc` library (before 2.34), typically on an older OS version, or if you know what you are doing, tweak your Makefile (to remove the explicit `libdl.so` requirement).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a symbolic link like so:

```
$ whereis libdl.so.2
libdl.so.2: /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 /usr/lib32/libdl.so.2
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 /usr/lib/libdl.so
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/libdl.so.2 /usr/lib32/libdl.so
```

In my case that's enough for MonoGame.

Comment: But why are those links missing? Manually doing things in /usr/lib is not a good idea so the actual cause and solution would be nice.